# Using object when out of scope?

Tags: c++

I'm working on a school assignment require to create a char LinkedList from user string input based on a menu of options:

> 1. Enter new string and store as linked list character of in an LinkedList class.
> 2. Get current length from the LinkedList.
> 3. Find index of character in this linked list.
> 4. Append another LinkedList to this LinkedList.

I have everything working fine, but now I'm stuck at the menu option part.
So let's say I choose option 1 to enter a string, and then I decide to use that object for case 2 and 3 to get the size and find index. That would not work because the object will be destroyed when out of scope. Is there any proper way that I can use to implement this ?

**Simple Code Below**

```
switch(option){
case 1:
 LinkedList ls1(getInput());
 ls1.printList();
 break;
}
case 2:
cout << "Size of LinkedList: " <<ls1.getSize() << endl; //wouldn't work because ls1 got destroyed when out of scope. 
}
```

Comment: You need some place to store the current linked list and you haven't created any such place. The `LinkedList` you did create doesn't exist if `option` is `2`.

Comment: The OP didn't deserve all the downvotes. Yes, it is about homework, but the question is precise and has a correct, straight forward answer.

Comment: @JeffreysupportsMonica I have up voted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to initiate the object outside the switch statement and after that you could use that object within any switch case.

Example:

```
ClassName ObjectName(getInput());
 switch(option){
   case 1: ObjectName.printList();
                 break;  
   case 2: cout << "Size of LinkedList: " <<ObjectName.getSize() << endl; 
                 break;
   default: break;
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to expand the scope of an object, you declare it at a higher scope. You probably have a `while` loop asking for input, and then switching on that input? If you want your `LinkedList` to survive successive iterations of the loop, you'll need to declare it before the loop starts.

```
LinkedList ls1; // required default constructor
int option = 3;
do
{
    std::cout << "Enter 1 to create new list. 2 to print current list. 3 to quit: ";
    std::cin >> option;
    switch(option)
    {
    case 1:
        ls1 = getInput(); // requires conversion from getInput()'s return type and copy (or preferably move) assignment operators
        ls1.printList();
        break;
    case 2:
        std::cout << "Size of LinkedList: " <<ls1.getSize() << std::endl;
        break;
    }
} while(option != 3);
```

Comment: Downvote for using a bad practice of an unitialized variable which yields undefined behavior. If the user fails to recognize the input prompt, the program will yield unexpected results.

Answer (score 2):

Declare the object outside the switch statement.

```
 LinkedList ls1(getInput());
 switch(option){
    case 1:
       ls1.printList();
       break;  
   case 2:
      cout << "Size of LinkedList: " <<ls1.getSize() << endl; 
      break;
   default:
      break;
 }
```